# subtract days from a Calendar time stored as text in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

So I take the current date in Kotlin:

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -daysAgo)
```

I store it as text on a label: time = calendar.time.toString()

Next, I want to subtract 2 days from the label text:

```
val date = LocalDate.parse(time)    
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.time = java.sql.Date.valueOf(date.toString())
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -daysAgo)
```

Method threw 'java.time.format.DateTimeParseException' exception after this line:       LocalDate.parse(time) any thoughts?

Comment: this sounds more complicated than it needs to be... what are you trying to accomplish? Do you really need a label? what's the purpose of that label? If you really need that label, then you probably only want it to display your data (labels are usually read-only to the user)... so you can keep your actual date-object and work with that... when need arises you just update (or your binding framework of choice updates) your label/view...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the new time API which is available since JDK 8 and can be found in `java.time`. You should also agree on a format that is being used:

```
val format = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME
val current = LocalDateTime.now()
val currentAsText = current.format(format)
println(currentAsText) // e.g. 2019-02-27T12:00:00.000

val fromText = LocalDateTime.parse(currentAsText, format)
val twoDaysAgo = fromText.minusDays(2)
println(twoDaysAgo) // 2019-02-27T12:00:00.000
```

Comment: working, but not usable with custom input

Answer (score 1):

From [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class:

> public String toString() 
>   Converts this Date object to a String of the form: 
>  
>   dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy

this results in this format:

```
Fri Feb 22 11:45:35 EET 2019
```

You need [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to parse this format, like this:

```
val date = ZonedDateTime 
    .parse(time, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH))
    .toLocalDate()
```